# return from array of objects with multiple conditons applied using map

Tags: javascript

I have an array as:

```
const productInfo = [
  {
    product: "NON_PROD",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD1",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD0",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD2",
      },
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD1",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD4",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD2",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD5",
      },
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD6",
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

I want to get all the subProd values in an array except for NON_PROD product and also if the product is PROD0 it should return the product i.e PROD0 and for others it should return all the subProd values like:

```
subProdList = [PROD0,SUBPROD4,SUBPROD5,SUBPROD6]
```

I have tried this piece of code:

```
  const list = productInfo.map((prod) => {
    if (prod.product === "PROD0") {
      return prod.product;
    } else {
      prod.subProducts.map((subProduct) => {
        return subProduct.subProd;
      });
    }
  });
```

but its not working

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the products with a loop, and use `map` when you concatenate the inner arrays with your output array.

```js
const productInfo=[{product:"NON_PROD",subProducts:[{subProd:"SUBPROD1"}]},{product:"PROD0",subProducts:[{subProd:"SUBPROD2"},{subProd:"SUBPROD3"}]},{product:"PROD1",subProducts:[{subProd:"SUBPROD4"}]},{product:"PROD2",subProducts:[{subProd:"SUBPROD5"},{subProd:"SUBPROD6"}]}];

let out = [];

for (const obj of productInfo) {
  const { product, subProducts } = obj;
  if (product !== 'NON_PROD') {
    if (product === 'PROD0') {
      out.push('PROD0');
    } else {
      out = [...out, ...subProducts.map(p => p.subProd)];
    }
  }
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Their requirement has some more conditions.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const productInfo = [
  {
    product: "NON_PROD",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD1",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD0",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD2",
      },
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD1",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD4",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD2",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD5",
      },
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD6",
      },
    ],
  },
];
  
const list = productInfo.filter(x=> x.product != "NON_PROD").flatMap((prod) => {
    let op = prod.subProducts.map((subProduct) => {
        return subProduct.subProd;
      });
    if (prod.product === "PROD0") {
     op.push(prod.product);
    } 
    return op;
  });
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

Push your necessary values to a new variable inside map could solve this

```js
const productInfo = [
  {
    product: "NON_PROD",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD1",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD0",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD2",
      },
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD3",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD1",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD4",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    product: "PROD2",
    subProducts: [
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD5",
      },
      {
        subProd: "SUBPROD6",
      },
    ],
  },
];




let list = []
productInfo.forEach((prod) => {
  if(prod.product !== 'NON_PROD') {
    if (prod.product === "PROD0") {
      list.push(prod.product)
    } else {
      list = [...list, ...prod.subProducts.map((subProduct) => subProduct.subProd)];
     }
  }
});
console.log(list)
```

Comment: If you want just to run a loop, make use for `Array.forEach` instead of `Array.map`

Comment: Can we remove the subProd values for PROD0. I want only the product value not the subProd values for PROD0

Comment: Yes,  i will update my answer

Comment: answer is updated as you need @Akshaykumar

Answer (score 0):

`Array.map` with `Array.flat` will help.

See code comments for logic

```js
const productInfo = [
  { product: "NON_PROD", subProducts: [{ subProd: "SUBPROD1" }] },
  { product: "PROD0", subProducts: [{ subProd: "SUBPROD2" }, { subProd: "SUBPROD3" }] },
  { product: "PROD1", subProducts: [{ subProd: "SUBPROD4" }] },
  { product: "PROD2", subProducts: [{ subProd: "SUBPROD5" }, { subProd: "SUBPROD6" }] },
];
const subProdList = productInfo.map(prod => {
  // If product is 'NON_PROD' return empty array.
  if (prod.product === "NON_PROD") {
    return [];
  }
  // If product is 'PROD0' return the product.
  if (prod.product === "PROD0") {
    return prod.product;
  }
  // return the subProd for all other combination than NON_PROD and PROD0
  return prod.subProducts.map(item => item.subProd);
  // Flat the array to make the two dimensional array to single dimension
}).flat();
console.log(subProdList);
```

Comment: i dont want the subProd values of PROD0, only its product value is required

Comment: @Akshaykumar your initial expected output was `['PROD0', 'SUBPROD2', 'SUBPROD3', 'SUBPROD4', 'SUBPROD5', 'SUBPROD6']`. Thats why I put subProd values for PROD0 as well in the output. Updated the anser for latest requirement. Please check the updated fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const productInfo = [
      {
        product: "NON_PROD",
        subProducts: [
          {
            subProd: "SUBPROD1",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        product: "PROD0",
        subProducts: [
          {
            subProd: "SUBPROD2",
          },
          {
            subProd: "SUBPROD3",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        product: "PROD1",
        subProducts: [
          {
            subProd: "SUBPROD4",
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        product: "PROD2",
        subProducts: [
          {
            subProd: "SUBPROD5",
          },
          {
            subProd: "SUBPROD6",
          },
        ],
      },
    ];
    let arr = [];
    const list = productInfo.map(prod => {
      if (prod.product != 'NON_PROD') {
        let op = prod.subProducts.map((subProduct) => {
          return subProduct.subProd;
        });
        if (prod.product === "PROD0") {
          op.push(prod.product);
        }
        op.map(el => {
          arr.push(el)
        })
        return op;
      }
    });
    console.log('??', arr);
```